# Open and list a function while debugging w. GDB

Tags: gdb

How can I open or view or list a function while using GDB, stepping does not work.

Example:

```
        if (strcmp(argv[1],"s")==0)
(gdb) s
          unsigned int a = functionINeed(argv[1]);
(gdb) s
          if (!a)
(gdb) s
        test(argv[1]);
```

My question is how can I view "functionINeed" ?

Comment: Did you compile the code for functionINeed() yourself or is this in an external library?

Comment: To be able to "step inside" a function call, the library file you are checking had to be compiled with debugging information included (-g) and you will also need to have access to the source files for it - do you have those and do you know if it was compiled that way? Otherwise *I think* all you will be able to do is step through assembly code by using the "si" command...